# What can I do to remove or minimize this code duplication that will provide the same functionality and behavior?

Tags: c++, refactoring, c++17, code-duplication

I have a set of derived classes and I'm using a function to update their internal ID values automatically upon class instantiation or creation. Originally I had this function in their base or superclass and it was working giving me correct results. However, as a design decision, I'm in the process of changing this behavior.

In the first version, every time a `Component` object was being constructed, the appended numerical value was being incremented even when the sub-types were different. I don't want this behavior. I want each subclass to start at `[0]` and count up...

I moved the function that performed this calculation appending the new value to the member `string` id from the base class to the derived classes. However, this is now creating code duplication, and with this current design, every future subclass would have to implement this function...

I want the same functionality and behavior that I currently have, but without the code duplication!

---

This is my current output which is the behavior I'm looking for with the displaying of the IDs:

```
Successfully connected Wire_001 to Wire_005
         from Wire_001 to Bus_000
Successfully connected Wire_002 to Wire_006
         from Wire_002 to Bus_000
Successfully connected Wire_003 to Wire_007
         from Wire_003 to Bus_000
Successfully connected Wire_000 to Wire_005
         from Wire_000 to Bus_000
Component Wire_000 already exists in Wire_004!
         from Wire_000 to Bus_000

Successfully connected Wire_001 to Wire_000
Successfully connected Wire_002 to Wire_001
Successfully connected Wire_003 to Wire_002
Successfully connected Wire_000 to Wire_003

Successfully connected Wire_004 to Wire_008
         from Wire_004 to Bus_001
Successfully connected Wire_005 to Wire_009
         from Wire_005 to Bus_001
Successfully connected Wire_006 to Wire_010
         from Wire_006 to Bus_001
Successfully connected Wire_007 to Wire_011
         from Wire_007 to Bus_001

These are my connected components:
        Wire_004 has Wire_000

        Wire_005 has Wire_001 Wire_000

        Wire_006 has Wire_002

        Wire_007 has Wire_003
```

---

Here's my current source code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <exception>

#include "Bus.h"

int main() {
    try {
        Wire w1, w2, w3, w4;
        std::cout << w1.id() << " " << w2.id() << " " << w3.id() << " "<< w4.id() << "\n\n";

        Bus<4> b1;

        b1.connect(&w1, 0);
        b1.connect(&w2, 1);
        b1.connect(&w3, 2);
        b1.connect(&w4, 3);

        b1.connect(&w1, 1);  // Valid Connection: same wire to multiple bus wires
        b1.connect(&w1, 0);  // Invalid Connection: trying to connect a same wire to the same bus wire multiple times...
        std::cout << "\n";

        Bus<4> b2;
        w1.connect(&w2);
        w2.connect(&w3);
        w3.connect(&w4);
        w4.connect(&w1);
        std::cout << "\n";

        b2.connect(&b1.wire(0), 0);
        b2.connect(&b1.wire(1), 1);
        b2.connect(&b1.wire(2), 2);
        b2.connect(&b1.wire(3), 3);

        std::cout << "\nThese are my connected components:\n";
        for( size_t i = 0; i < b2.size(); i++ ) {
            for (auto& component : b2.myConnections(i)) {
                std::cout << "\t" << component->id() << " has ";
                auto connections = component->myConnections();
                for (auto& c : connections) {
                    std::cout << c->id() << " ";
                }
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
                     
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Component.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <assert.h>   
#include <memory>    
#include <array>
#include <list>    
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>
#include <sstream>    

class Component {
protected:
    std::string id_ = "";
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Component>> components_;

    explicit Component(const std::string& id) : id_{ id } {}

public:
    virtual ~Component() {}

    std::string& id() { return id_; }

    void connect(Component* other) {
        for (auto& l : components_) {
            if (other->id_ == l->id()) {
                std::cout << "Component " << other->id_ << " already exists in " << id_ << "!\n";
                return;
            }
        }

        components_.push_back( std::make_shared<Component>( *other ) );
        std::cout << "Successfully connected " << other->id() << " to " << id_ << "\n";
    }

    virtual std::list<std::shared_ptr<Component>> myConnections() { return components_; }    
    virtual void propagate() {};    
};
```

**Wire.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Component.h"

class Wire : public Component {
private:

public:
    explicit Wire(const std::string& name = "Wire") : Component(name) {
        updateId();
    };
       
    virtual ~Wire() {}

    virtual void propagate() override {
        return;
    }

private:
    void updateId() {
        static int i = 0;
        std::stringstream strValue;
        strValue << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << std::to_string(i++);
        id_.append("_" + strValue.str());
    }
};
```

**Bus.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Wire.h"

template<size_t BusSize>
class Bus : public Component {
private:
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Wire>, BusSize> bus_interface_;

public:
    explicit Bus(const std::string& name = "Bus") : Component(name) {
        updateId();
        createBus();
    }

    virtual ~Bus() {}

    virtual void propagate() override {
        return;
    }

    void connect(Component* component, size_t index) {
        assert(index < BusSize);
        assert(component != nullptr);
        bus_interface_[index]->connect(component);
        std::cout << "\t from " << component->id() << " to " << id_ << "\n";
    }

    Wire& wire(size_t index) {
        assert(index < BusSize);
        return *bus_interface_[index].get();
    }

    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Wire>, BusSize> bus() { return bus_interface_; }

    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Component>> myConnections(size_t index) { 
        assert(index < BusSize);
        return bus_interface_[index]->myConnections();
    }

    size_t size() const { return BusSize; }

private:
    void updateId() {
        static int i = 0;
        std::stringstream strValue;
        strValue << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << std::to_string(i++);
        id_.append("_" + strValue.str());
    }

    void createBus() {
        size_t i = 0;
        for (auto& w : bus_interface_) {
            w = std::shared_ptr<Wire>(new Wire);
        }
    }
};
```

---

As you can see from the two subclasses, their member function `::updateId()`:

```
void updateId() {
    static int i = 0;
    std::stringstream strValue;
    strValue << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << std::to_string(i++);
    id_.append("_" + strValue.str());
}
```

is the code duplication that I'm concerned with. What can I do to remove the dependency of this code duplication while keeping the same functionality and behavior?

Comment: This might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @chris That may be so... but I usually resort to here first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp). Add a templated second base class to hold the ID handling code.

```
template <class T>
class ComponentID {
public:
    ComponentID(std::string &id_) {
        // Same as updateID above
    }
};

class Wire: public Component, ComponentID<Wire> {
public:
    Wire(const std::string& name = "Wire") : Component(name), ComponentID(id_) {
    }
    // ...
};

template<size_t BusSize>
class Bus : public Component, ComponentID<Bus<BusSize>> {
    public:
        explicit Bus(const std::string& name = "Bus") : Component(name), ComponentID(id_) {
            createBus();
        }
        // ...
};
```

We're passing in the `id_` field from the `Component` base class to the `ComponentID` constructor so that it can be updated without having to change the access to `id`.

Comment: I like the proposal of using `CRTP` and my `Wire` class seems to work fine, but I'm having issues with my `Bus` class... When I try to do this for its declaration: `class Bus : public Component, ComponentID<Bus>` Visual Studio is generating: `C3203` about unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter... And when I change it to this: `class Bus : public Component, ComponentID<Bus<BusSize>>` it then generates: `C2512` no appropriate default constructor and `C2614` `Bus<4>` illegal member initialization...

Comment: I'm wondering if I should inherit the `Bus` class from the `Wire` class considering that it is a collection of wires... Also, the `createBus()` call isn't within the `Wire` constructor... not at least within my current source code.

Comment: I tried to inherit Bus from Wire and got the code to compile and work, however, all of the id's even for the busses had the name `wire`... I then tried to push the name from the `Bus` constructor into the `Wire`'s constructor and it did give me Bus for the ID, however, the Bus's numbering wasn't Bus_000 and Bus_001 that I'm after, it was incrementing from the last `wire` that was created... Close, but not quite...

Comment: @FrancisCugler I've had a chance to experiment with this, and have fixed the typos I had and added an example for `Bus`. I haven't tried to derive it from `Wire`, but you'd want to pass the `Bus` name parameter to the Wire constructor, something like  `Bus(... name): Wire(name) ...`

Comment: I eventually did that when I found a working solution using your CRTP structure...